# Python : Sending a variable to another script without run

Tags: python

I want change value in Script1.py from Script2.py but Script1 always running. For example;

Script1.py

```
count = 0
while(count == 0):
    print (count)
```

Script2.py

```
// I want change count and break loop here when Script1.py running
```

Comment: you will need to have some sort of communication, its fairly easy to set up a socket connection and have script1 check if there is data on the channel and act accordingly somewhere in the loop, or even have its own thread thats always listening to the channel [here](https://realpython.com/python-sockets/) is a guide with good examples

Answer (score 2):

Write in `Script2.py` :

```
import Script1
Script1.count = 1
```

You should put the `while` loop of `Script1.py` inside a function or `Script2.py` will never exit the `import` statement and `Script1.count` will never be modified.

This lets you modify `count` in `Scripy1.py` before the loop starts. If you want to modify it while the loop is running, I don't know how to do it. But it's something you should not do.

Comment: I don't think this changes the value of the variable in Script2 dynamically when there is a change in script1

Comment: Yes it does but the `while` loop must not be written with no protection in `Script1.py` because then `Script2.py` will never get out of the `import` statement and `count` will never be modified. Defining this loop in a function makes it exit the `import` statement correctly and then you can see it works.

Comment: If you really want it modified while the `while` loop is running, I think you're gonna need multiprocessing so that a worker can modify `count` while another runs the `while` loop.

Comment: @Asharhing you said : "you need some multiprocessing step to have both running together." Can you give me example on code ?

Comment: Actually I tested it and multiprocessing won't work because the `while` loop process will be refered to the environment state at the moment it started and the modified `count` won't reach it because it was done after the first process started. I don't know how to have it modified while the `while` loop is running. What I wrote lets you modify it before the loop starts.

Answer (score 1):

you could try putting the variable inside another file were one script writes to the file and another just reads it.

something like this

```
**script 1. writes to the file**

for x in range(1,100):

    file1 = open("MyFile.txt","w") # open file as write

    file1.write(str(x))

    file1.close() # has to close or it will be appended instead of over writing it 

**script 2. reads the file**

file2=open("MyFile.txt", "r")

if file2.read==Somevalue :

   do something.
```